# Hot sd card. will not boot

Tags: pi-3

When I got my PI-3 kit from canakit everything worked fine. I had it in a case but took it out to make some measurements for a project. When I plugged it in the next day it would not boot up. I turned it over and the sd card burned my  finger. I immediately pulled out and found the there was a short. I made a new sd card and stuck it in. (Whilst unplugged) It would not boot up. Any suggestions to what might have happened?      Only used it twice since Christmas btw

Comment: Do you mind rephrasing your post in a simple English? And please make sure to ask a clear question. I don't quite understand what you ask about. The gist seems to be: "*whilst unplugged it would not boot up; any suggestions?*"

Comment: @techraf I think what he means is that he felt the sd card overheat and when he removed it he noticed a short circuit between the sd card pins and then eye. A new sd card was inserted his Pi failed to boot

Comment: Was the SD Card plugged in while you removed the Pi from the case?

Comment: I have this. New Pi 3B+. Worked fine Thursday Friday. Left over weekend sd card v hot and will not boot.

Answer (score 2):

If you shorted the Pi and subsequently it overheated an SD card and now will not boot, then it is probably toast.

However, if there are no signs of life (none of the leds come on, etc.), you could leave it unplugged for a day or two in hope the main [polyfuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse) is just blown. The "hot SD card when I found it" implies that's probably not the case, but you might as well try.

Comment: This parrot is no more! He has ceased to be! 'E's expired and gone to meet 'is maker!

Comment: Mine too. Is it the SD card or the pi. I was using the power supply for the pi; the PCB I had under test has a bandgap vref on it, so I know the pi power-supply (as supplied in the started box) was giving out 5.2V. Little bit high, but I dont understand why this might have destroyed the SD card.